# Help with the river model of black holes

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, event-horizon

I've been reading the paper "[The river model of black holes](https://arXiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0411060)" by Andrew Hamilton et. al., but I've been unable to derive the paper's results on the tetrad frame connection coefficients. I must be doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what it is.

To indicate, in a simple way, what is my problem, let's consider a Kerr black hole, but let's assume that there is no rotation, i.e., that $a=0$. In this case, as one can easily conclude from Eqs. (24), (31), (32) and (73) from the paper,

$$\begin{aligned}
&R = \rho =r,\\
&\beta^\mu = \beta \left(0,-\frac x r,-\frac y r,-\frac z r\right), \\
&\alpha_\mu = (1,0,0,0), \\
&\zeta^i = (0,0,0,0).
\end{aligned}$$

I consider indexes as varying in $\{0,1,2,3\}$, unless otherwise indicated. Equation (71) from the paper gives the expression of the connection coefficients:

$$\Gamma_{kmn} = -\frac{\partial \omega_{km}}{\partial x^n}, \tag{71}$$

with

$$ \omega_{km} = \alpha_k\beta_m-\alpha_m\beta_k+\varepsilon_{0kmi}\zeta^i. \tag{72}  $$

In our case, this yields the nonzero connection coefficients (with $m,n \in \{1,2,3\}$)

$$\begin{align}
\Gamma_{0mn} &= -\frac{\partial \beta_m}{\partial x^n}, &\tag{a} \\
\Gamma_{m0n} &= \frac{\partial \beta_m}{\partial x^n}. &\tag{b}
\end{align}$$

In Eqs. (72), (a) and (b), numerically, $\beta_0 = -\beta^0 = 0$, and $\beta_m = \beta^m = \delta_\mu^m \beta^\mu$ (with $m \in \{1,2,3\}$), because the coordinates $x^n$ have Minkowski metric and are numerically equal to the coordinates $x^\mu$, as indicated in the top-right paragraph of page 10 of the paper.

The paper doesn't give the derivation of Eq. (71). To have a derivation of the connection coefficients, I tried to compute them through Eq. (69):

$$ \Gamma_{kmn} = \frac 1 2 \left( \frac{\partial \alpha_m \beta_k}{\partial x^n} - \frac{\partial \alpha_k \beta_m}{\partial x^n} + \frac{\partial \alpha_m \beta_n}{\partial x^k} - \frac{\partial \alpha_n \beta_k}{\partial x^m} + \frac{\partial \alpha_n \beta_m}{\partial x^k} - \frac{\partial \alpha_k \beta_n}{\partial x^m} \right). \tag{69} $$

The derivatives in this equation are nonzero only if the index of $\alpha$ is zero and the indexes of $\beta$ and $x$ are nonzero. Therefore, we have the following nonzero connection coefficients (with $m,n \in \{1,2,3\}$):

$$\begin{align}
\Gamma_{0mn} &= -\frac 1 2 \left( \frac{\partial \beta_m}{\partial x^n} + \frac{\partial \beta_n}{\partial x^m} \right) &\tag{c} \\
\Gamma_{m0n} &= \frac 1 2 \left( \frac{\partial \beta_m}{\partial x^n} + \frac{\partial \beta_n}{\partial x^m} \right) &\tag{d}  \\
\Gamma_{mn0} &= \frac 1 2 \left( \frac{\partial \beta_n}{\partial x^m} - \frac{\partial \beta_m}{\partial x^n} \right). &\tag{e}
\end{align}$$

These are different from the results (a), (b) from the paper. As a check, I tried computing the connection coefficients in a few other ways too, and always got (c), (d), (e). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out the answer. The two derivatives that appear in the right-hand side of (c), (d), (e) are equal to each other. Therefore, (c) and (d) are equivalent to (a) and (b), respectively, and (e) yields $\Gamma_{mn0}=0$.

A simple way to see that the two partial derivatives are equal, is to note that $\beta_m$, with $m\in\{1,2,3\}$, has spherical symmetry, which implies that it is the spatial gradient of some spatial scalar field $\phi$. Given this, the equality of the partial derivatives in (c), (d), (e) follows from the equality of mixed partial derivatives of $\phi$: with $m,n \in \{1,2,3\}$,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \beta_m}{\partial x^n} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x^n} \left( \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^m} \right) \\
                                      &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x^m} \left( \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^n} \right) \\
                                      &= \frac{\partial \beta_n}{\partial x^m}.
\end{align}$$